# C++/LLVM: Runtime code generation and STL container

Tags: c++, stl, llvm, jit

Assume a simple partial evaluation scenario:

```
#include <vector>

/* may be known at runtime */
int someConstant();

/* can be partially evaluated */
double foo(std::vector<double> args) {
  return args[someConstant()] * someConstant();
}
```

Let's say that `someConstant()` is known and does not change at runtime (e.g. given by the user once) and can be replaced by the corresponding int literal. If `foo` is part of the hot path, I expect a significant performance improvement:

```
/* partially evaluated, someConstant() == 2 */
double foo(std::vector<double> args) {
  return args[2] * 2;
}
```

My current take on that problem would be to generate LLVM IR at runtime, because I know the structure of the partially evaluated code (so I would not need a general purpose partial evaluator). 
So I want to write a function `foo_ir` that generates IR code that does the same thing as `foo`, but not calling `someConstant()`, because it is known at runtime.
Simple enough, isn't it? Yet, when I look at the generated IR for the code above:

```
 ; Function Attrs: uwtable
define double @_Z3fooSt6vectorIdSaIdEE(%"class.std::vector"* %args) #0 {
  %1 = call i32 @_Z12someConstantv()
  %2 = sext i32 %1 to i64
  %3 = call double* @_ZNSt6vectorIdSaIdEEixEm(%"class.std::vector"* %args, i64 %2)
  %4 = load double* %3
  %5 = call i32 @_Z12someConstantv()
  %6 = sitofp i32 %5 to double
  %7 = fmul double %4, %6
  ret double %7
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define linkonce_odr double* @_ZNSt6vectorIdSaIdEEixEm(%"class.std::vector"* %this, i64 %__n) #1 align 2 {
  %1 = alloca %"class.std::vector"*, align 8
  %2 = alloca i64, align 8
  store %"class.std::vector"* %this, %"class.std::vector"** %1, align 8
  store i64 %__n, i64* %2, align 8
  %3 = load %"class.std::vector"** %1
  %4 = bitcast %"class.std::vector"* %3 to %"struct.std::_Vector_base"*
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds %"struct.std::_Vector_base"* %4, i32 0, i32 0
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds %"struct.std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_Vector_impl"* %5, i32 0, i32 0
  %7 = load double** %6, align 8
  %8 = load i64* %2, align 8
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds double* %7, i64 %8
  ret double* %9
}
```

I see, that the `[]` was included from the STL definition (function `@_ZNSt6vectorIdSaIdEEixEm`) - fair enough. The problem is: It could as well be some member function, or even a direct data access, I simply cannot assume the data layout to be the same everywhere, so at development-time, I do not know the concrete `std::vector` layout of the host machine.

Is there some way to use C++ metaprogramming to get the required information at compile time? i.e. is there some way to ask llvm to provide IR for `std::vector`'s `[]` method?

As a bonus: I would prefer to not enforce the compilation of the library with clang, instead, LLVM shall be a runtime-dependency, so just invoking clang at compile time (even if I do not know how to do this) is a second-best solution.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I completely fail to understand the basic problem you are trying to solve. Could you perhaps clarify? Specifically, what do you mean by "partially evaluate"? Why do you mean by having a method which is "known at run-time" - while having a "constant" in its name? Why do you write that `[]` was inlined but you pasted 2 distinct functions, and the 1st does not inline the 2nd?

Comment: I use the term partial evaluation in the classic meaning of reducing a term based on some (partially) fixed input. I tried to elaborate the problem a little bit. My actual problem is that the definition of `[]` depends on the host (compiling) system of my lib, so I cannot make any assumptions at development time. Instead I need to get the `std::vector` layout at compile time somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question:

While I still have no solution for the general case (e.g. `std::map`), there exists a simple solution for `std::vector`:

According to [the C++ standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/), the following holds for the member function `data()`

> Returns a direct pointer to the memory array used internally by the
>   vector to store its owned elements.
>
> Because elements in the vector are guaranteed to be stored in
>   contiguous storage locations in the same order as represented by the
>   vector, the pointer retrieved can be offset to access any element in
>   the array.

So in fact, the object-level layout of `std::vector` is fixed by the standard.